# TYPO3 Exception: #1436717322: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed – What can I do?

Tags: exception, typo3, typo3-11.x

I’m out of my depth with these error messages that have been popping up in my TYPO3 log for a couple of weeks now, sometimes loads of them within just a couple of minutes.

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1436717322: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed | InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /.../typo3_src-11.5.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php in line 125. Requested URL: https:///
```

---

*[edit of the original post, following notes in the comments]*

The TYPO3 log file showed the following expanded message:

```
Tue, 31 Jan 2023 13:15:22 +0000
[CRITICAL] request="7331e1d6281d8"
component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): InvalidArgumentException, code #1436717322, file /path/to/typo3_src-11.5.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php, line 125: The parsedUri "https:///" appears to be malformed -
{"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"InvalidArgumentException","exception_code":1436717322,"file":"/path/to/typo3_src-11.5.22/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php","line":125,"message":"The parsedUri \"https:///\" appears to be malformed","request_url":"https:///","exception":null}
```

*[edit end]*

*[edit 4 August 2023]*

After finally figuring out how to restrict access to the backend (application_mode:BE led me to the conclusion, this might help) I had another such exception. Here’s the respective entry from the Apache `ssl-access.log` with a 500 status code for, apparently, the root page of my website:

```
193.106.29.122 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:33:47 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 10878 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

(the typo3 exception was logged at `04 Aug 2023 06:33:47 +0000`)

*[edit end]*

---

The actual parsedUri value differs and can be something like `https:///index1.php` or `https:///aspnet_client`, and many others.

I have no idea how something like this can be sent to the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\Uri` class. Can anybody explain this?

There is a [docs entry for the exception](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1436717322.html) which also doesn’t help me.

In my `typo3conf/sites/[my-website]/config.yaml` I have defined the base:

```yaml
websiteTitle: 'My Website'
base: 'https://www.my-web.site/'
```

I would like this to end. To me they look like attempted attacks and even though they are apparently blocked, they might lead to something more serious and they do clutter my log obscuring other entries I might want to tackle.

Comment: Can you narrow this exception to a page or to a special functionality on your website? It's hard to find the reason with that information.

Comment: That is exactly part of my problem: I don’t know how to narrow it down. I only see this exception in the log with no more details. Is there a way to see a stacktrace for logged exceptions? Maybe this should have been a dedicated question instead of just a note in the question above …

Comment: You can take a look into the `var/log/typo3_xxx.log` file if there is much more information, maybe also the error log from your webserver. You also can deactivate one extension after another to narrow it down.

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasLöffler! The log file contained some additional information that leads me to the conclusion that this happens in the backend. It has me guessing that someone is trying to access the backend who shouldn’t. I’ll try and block the access via the web server configuration. I’ve added the extended error message to the original post.

Comment: You could also check the servers access log to find out which request is causing the error.